# How can a reference escape a closure? `packet` escapes the closure body here

Tags: rust

In the following example, I don t understand why it complains about `packet` escaping the closure. Yes, `packet` has a short lifetime, it lives only as long as `on_packet` function call lasts. However, when I call `on_packet_render(&packet)`, I'm not moving `packet`, I'm just passing a reference, which will be used and the `on_packet_render` call will return while I'm inside `on_packet`, so I don't see why this error.

```
use std::sync::Arc;
pub type DecoderProvider = Arc<dyn Fn(&dyn Fn(&Option<&Arc<u8>>))>;
trait DecodedPacket<'a, T> {}

fn main() {
    let mut on_packet_render = |packet: &Option<Box<dyn DecodedPacket<u8>>>| {
        if let Some(packet) = packet {
            
        }
    };
    let mut on_packet: Arc<
        dyn for<'c, 'd> FnMut(
            Option<Box<dyn DecodedPacket<'c, u8> + 'd>>,
        )> = Arc::new(|packet| {
        on_packet_render(&packet);
    });
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=aa1750a11f06b822ce80acd086deaffc)

Error:

```
error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of closure
  --> src/main.rs:15:9
   |
6  |     let mut on_packet_render = |packet: &Option<Box<dyn DecodedPacket<u8>>>| {
   |         -------------------- `on_packet_render` declared here, outside of the closure body
...
14 |         )> = Arc::new(|packet| {
   |                        ------ `packet` is a reference that is only valid in the closure body
15 |         on_packet_render(&packet);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `packet` escapes the closure body here
```

Comment: Not sure if this is a proper answer, but your code [compiles](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1b23a410b8cdbb7d53a26beba8b6b28e) if you remove the `'d` stuff.

Comment: Seems that the elided lifetimes work fine if the explicit lifetimes are removed. Are these explicit lifetime declarations necessary?